# What is the easiest way to join 12 columns?

Tags: text, scripting, awk

I have 12 columns separated by a tab. How can I join them side-by-side?

**[Added]** You can also tell me other methods as AWK: the faster the better.

Comment: @UT, is there some reason why you *have* to use awk?

Comment: No, I want the simplest method.

Comment: AWK is a chainsaw, you want a breadknife :-). Try cut instead, it's more suited to tab-separated input and re-arranging/combining columns.

Comment: Added some tags to the question, I hope they are appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you asked specifically about awk (there are tools better suited to the job), the following is a first-cut solution:

```
awk '{print $1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10$11$12}'
```

A more complicated and configurable solution, where you could change the number of columns used for output, would be:

```
awk -v lim=12 '{for(x=1;x<lim;x++){printf "%s",$x};print ""}'
```

Other possibilities, if you're not restricted to awk, are:

```
tr -d '\011'                     # to combine ALL columns on the line.
cut --output-delimiter='' -f1-12 # more general (1-12 or 3-7 or 1-6,9).
```

Based on your edit and comments, I suggest cut is the best tool for the job. Use "`man cut`", "`info cut`" or "`cut --help`" for more details (this depends on your platform).

Answer (score 4):

If you are just using awk to concatenate the columns I would use 'tr' and delete tab

```
cat file1 | tr -d '\011'>  file2
```

Comment: The above doesn't car it just deletes all tabs and leaves all other chars the same

Comment: Thanks for all the downvotes - I know the OP asked about awk. But if someone asks how to knock in a screw with a hammer it is often worth pointing out the invention of the screwrdiver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    print $1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$(10)$(11)$(12)
}
```

I'm not an `awk` genius so I don't know if there's some sort of looping construct you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on your editor/command of choice. But generally, it boild down to replacing the  character with nothing.
For example, in vim: "`:%s/\t//g`"

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what tool you would like to use but any text editor would be able to replace the tab to an empty character, I guess that would work, that's what I  usually do.